# Apache 2.4.23 reports "server certificate does NOT include an ID", but everything works

Tags: ssl, apache-2.4, ssl-certificate

Apache (2.4, both versions .20 and .23) is sending the following waring to my error log:

```
[Tue Oct 04 09:17:02.438371 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 55157:tid 140100469708544] AH01909: <host>:<port>:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
```

However, when I go to https://host:port/... with Google Chrome, I get the green lock, and clicking on it and looking at the server information gives all the correct information about my server.

Is this an apache bug?  A failure of my understanding?

```
##
## SSL Virtual Host Context
##

<VirtualHost _default_:<port>>
DocumentRoot "<the path>"
ServerName <host>:<port>
```

Should I replace "*default*" with my host name?

openssl x509 -in [cert file] -noout -subject

-->

subject= .../OU=PlatinumSSL/CN=[host]

So I have defined the server name correctly in the conf file, and the certificate has the host name correctly listed.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a warning.

It is logical that you define the directive ServerName to specify which url you are serving, when you configure a certificate, httpd will match the name in ServerName against the CN in the certificate you are using.

This won't prevent httpd from running since it is not a fatal error or anything, but it just warns you because clients will complain.

About the VirtualHost directive, do not define names in it, names should be defined in ServerName as I mentioned above.

So briefly: make sure ServerName and CN or SAN in certificate match.

You can use this command to check the CN in your certificate:
`openssl x509 -in /path/to/cert.crt -noout -subject`

Also, if your certificate is a wildcard, the sane thing to do would be to define these directives in your virtualhost:

```
Servername example.com
ServerAlias *.example.com
```

Comment: ServerName and CN match.  I added that information to my question

Comment: "This won't prevent httpd from running since it is not a fatal error or anything, but it just warns you because clients will complain" The thing is, Google Chrome does NOT complain.  It thinks everything is just fine

Comment: Well, without seeing the actual data I can't tell you anything else aside from the extra ":0" in the error from Apache HTTPD looks odd "AH01909: <host>:<port>:0 server certificate". But anyways, if your client browser does not complain, just ignore it.

Comment: *httpd will match the name in ServerName against the CN..* Note that [RFC 2018](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2818#section-3.1) deprecated the use of Common Name as identifying the server - back in May, 2000.  And [RFC 6125](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6125#section-6.4.4) says the Common Name shall be ignored if SANs are present:  "As noted, a client MUST NOT seek a match for a reference identifier
   of CN-ID if the presented identifiers include a DNS-ID, SRV-ID,
   URI-ID, or any application-specific identifier types supported by the
   client."

Comment: @AndrewHenle thanks for the clarification. As you pointed out and AFAIK apache does take into account RFC 2018. So we should assume in cases like the question above, not the SAN and nor the CN matched the requested host name.

Comment: I'm adjusting my answer based on your spot on comment.

Comment: @AndrewHenle+ you meant 2818 (as you linked) not 2018. (And 6125 explicitly does not apply to HTTPS, or other already-defined protocols; see 1.4 and appendix B.) While 2818 requires (all) clients _prefer_ SAN to CN, Chrome since about 4 years ago goes further and _requires_ SAN -- it will not fall back to CN if SAN if absent, as other clients still do, so if Chrome _now_ accepts this cert we know it contains SAN (with at least one entry matching the request) without even looking.